# how to enable SQL Application Role via Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, application-role

I'm now developing big government application with entity framework. at first i have one problem about enable SQL application role. with ado.net I'm using below code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sys.sp_setapprole");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = _sqlConn;
            SqlParameter paramAppRoleName = new SqlParameter();
            paramAppRoleName.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            paramAppRoleName.ParameterName = "@rolename";
            paramAppRoleName.Value = "AppRole";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramAppRoleName);

            SqlParameter paramAppRolePwd = new SqlParameter();
            paramAppRolePwd.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            paramAppRolePwd.ParameterName = "@password";
            paramAppRolePwd.Value = "123456";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramAppRolePwd);

            SqlParameter paramCreateCookie = new SqlParameter();
            paramCreateCookie.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            paramCreateCookie.ParameterName = "@fCreateCookie";
            paramCreateCookie.DbType = DbType.Boolean;
            paramCreateCookie.Value = 1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCreateCookie);

            SqlParameter paramEncrypt = new SqlParameter();
            paramEncrypt.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            paramEncrypt.ParameterName = "@encrypt";
            paramEncrypt.Value = "none";
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramEncrypt);

            SqlParameter paramEnableCookie = new SqlParameter();
            paramEnableCookie.ParameterName = "@cookie";
            paramEnableCookie.DbType = DbType.Binary;
            paramEnableCookie.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            paramEnableCookie.Size = 1000;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramEnableCookie);

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlParameter outVal = cmd.Parameters["@cookie"];
                // Store the enabled cookie so that approle  can be disabled with the cookie.
                _appRoleEnableCookie = (byte[]) outVal.Value;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = false;
                msg = "Could not execute enable approle proc." + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message;
            }
```

But no matter how much I searched I could not find a way to implement on EF.

Another question is: how to Add Application Role to Entity data model designer?

---

I'm using the below code for execute parameter with EF:

```
AEntities ar = new AEntities();

            DbConnection con = ar.Connection;
            con.Open();
            msg = "";
            bool result = true;
            DbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            var d = new DbParameter[]{
            new SqlParameter{ ParameterName="@r", Value ="AppRole",Direction =  ParameterDirection.Input}
          , new SqlParameter{ ParameterName="@p", Value ="123456",Direction =  ParameterDirection.Input}
           };
            string sql = "EXEC " + procName + " @rolename=@r,@password=@p";
            var s = ar.ExecuteStoreCommand(sql, d);
```

When run ExecuteStoreCommand this line return error:

> Application roles can only be activated at the ad hoc level.

Comment: Have you tried ObjectContex.ExecuteStoreCommand(). The string you pass would be `'EXEC sys.sp_setapprole @rolename, @password, @fCreateCookie, ...'` and you would pass SqlParameters to provide values for the parameter placeholders in the command.

Answer (score 1):

I do it the following way (assuming Database First):

1. I create the DbContext from the db and call it MyEntitiesBase
2. I inherit from MyEntitiesBase to create MyEntities with the following code:

   ```
   public partial class MyEntities : MyEntitiesBase
   {

   private byte[] appRoleCookie;

   private void SetAppRole()
   {
       try
       {
           appRoleCookie = Database.SqlQuery<byte[]>(
               @"
               DECLARE @cookie VARBINARY(8000)
               DECLARE @r INT
               EXEC sp_setapprole 'user', 'pass', @fCreateCookie = true, @cookie = @cookie OUTPUT
               SELECT @cookie").First();
       }
       catch
       {
           throw new AuthenticationException();
       }
   }

   private void UnSetAppRole()
   {
       bool failed = Database.SqlQuery<bool>("DECLARE @result BIT; EXEC @result = sp_unsetapprole @cookie = " + appRoleCookie.ToHexadecimalString() + "; SELECT @result").First();
       if (failed)
           throw new SecurityException();
   }

   public MyEntities() : base()
   {
       Database.Connection.Open();
       SetAppRole();
   }

   private bool disposed = false;

   protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
       if (disposed)
           return;
       UnSetAppRole();
       Database.Connection.Close();
       disposed = true;
       base.Dispose(disposing);
   }
   }
   ```

Where `ToHexadecimalString` is an extension method for `IEnumerable<byte>`, as follows:

```
public static class BytesExtensions
{
    public static string ToHexadecimalString(this IEnumerable<byte> bytes)
    {
        return "0x" + string.Concat(bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
    }
}
```

And that's it. Works with connection pooling on and everything. You just use this inherited version instead of the one generated by EF.

Comment: I have just implemented this code using an IDbConnectionInterceptor in EF6 and works a treat. Call `SetAppRole` in the `Opened` method and `UnSetAppRole` in the `Closing` method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are doing is calling a stored procedure.

Entity Framework has functionality to excute stored procedures. Here is an explaination with a video: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

If your scrol down to the section "Using Import Functions to Map Stored Procedures" you will find the part that is relevant for you.